# proving or disproving a certain inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, large-deviation-theory

In the attempt of proving a large deviations result, the following quantity pops up:

$$H(\delta,h):= \frac{\frac{1}{2\alpha}(2\alpha-8\delta)+ \frac{4}{\alpha}\frac{1}{1-\gamma}\delta^{1-\gamma}}{h^{(\delta-\log(\delta)\delta)\frac{4}{\alpha}}} $$

where $\alpha \in (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})$ is fixed, $\gamma= 1-\frac{1}{\log_{h}(e)}$.

The result that I would need is: "there exists some vaules of $e>h>1$ and $\delta=\delta(h)>0$ such that $H(\delta_0,h)<1$ for all $\delta_0<\delta$.

Unfortunately, I believe this is not true, but I could not come up with a good proof. Can anyone help me understand if this is true or not and how to prove it?
Thanks

Comment: In the expression of $H$, right hand side, are the outermost parentheses redundant?

Comment: yes. I edited the question

Comment: I edited the equation to make it bigger. You may use double $$ rather than single $ to include equation.

Comment: In the denominator of $H$, by $\log(\delta)$, do you mean $\log_h (\delta)$ or $\ln \delta$? Also, $\log_h e = \frac{1}{\ln h}$, so $\gamma = 1 - \ln h$?

Comment: In the denominator I mean $\ln(\delta)$. And yes $\log_h(e)= \frac{1}{\ln(h)}$